# If completions are equal for any prime then the fields are equal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-extensions

**Question**
Suppose we have a finite cyclic Galois extension of fields $L/K$. Assume that for every prime $v$ of $K$ and any prime $w$ of $L$ over $v$ we have
$L_w\simeq K_v$.
I want to show that then $L\simeq K$.

**Ideas**
I am trying to show it by elementary means. I have tried to use the fact that the Galois group of the completions is isomorphic to the decomposition group. And this would mean that this group is trivial.
If this group is trivial, then the number of primes above any prime in $K$ is $[L:K]$, therefore the ramification indices and inertial degrees are both $1$ for any prime.

I feel like I am on the right track, because it seems that if both this quantities are one, then the primes $w$ are the same to the $v$? I am not sure how to follow from this. Any help is appreciated.
Comment: I have realised I have not used the fact that $L/K$ is cyclic in my approach, maybe this can help?

Comment: Do you really want "$=$" (equal) or just "$\cong$" (isomorphic)? Depending on the construction of completion, you might get strictly non-equal completins, but they should be isomorphic.

Comment: You are correct, I only need isomorphisms. I will correct it now. Thanks

Comment: Are you allowing yourself to use (some form of) the Chebotarev density theorem? You've reduced to the case that all but finitely many primes of $K$ split completely in $L$ (because you've shown that the decomposition group is trivial for all unramified $w/v$). Alternatively, you could use the argument in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354823/infinitely-many-primes-dont-split), which uses Dedekind zeta functions.

Comment: I am not sure how the density theorem would help? Moreover, I believe I have show that the decomposition groups are trivial for all primes, not only the unramified, right? So maybe that theorem is not even needed?

Comment: $\simeq$ a bit sloppy as $K((x))\cong K((x^2))$ though the decomposition group of $K(x)/K(x^2)$ at $x$ isn't trivial (say $char(K)\ne 2$). And $e=f=1$ doesn't mean that there is only one prime in $L$ above $v$.